# ruby - use gem 'whenever' to check the deadline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use 'whenever' this gem to check my all projects are still not out of deadline. I wrote this code but it didn't work and change status in the database. Can somebody give me some advises. Thank you for helping!

config/schedule.rb

```
set :environment, :development
every 1.day, at: '11:3 am' do
  rake 'project:close_project'
end
```

app/models/project.rb

```
def self.close_project(dt)
# 締切日が過ぎているプロジェクトを抽出
Project.where(deadline > dt).each do |project|
# 対象プロジェクトを終了状態に
  project.update!(status: 'closed') 
end
```

end

product.rake

```
namespace :product do
 task :close_project => :environment do
  Project.close_project(Date.today)
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever creates jobs based on CronJob format. So to run your jobs periodically, you should run `whenever` command and copy and pasting the results to crontab by running `crontab -e` or do this task automatically just by running `whenever -w`.